Jamo dependency UnicodeDecode error while cloning coqui ai/TTS repo
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of nltk to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.9-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.5/1.5 MB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jieba to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jieba
  Downloading jieba-0.42.tar.gz (19.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 19.2/19.2 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jamo to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jamo
  Downloading jamo-0.4.0.tar.gz (7.3 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\PREDATOR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7v9nk6vb\jamo_f37556e2e76541e389401ce26dcdd7e8\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
          long_description = f.read()
                             ^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\PREDATOR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 707: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I tried modifying the requirements.txt file but its unmodifiable.

You will need to provide information on the OS that you are working with. From first glance, this is a system setup issue.  If you can provide that and your requirements.txt, then we can help. I dont understand how that file is "unmodifiable" either.. More context would be helpful.

I'm getting the exact same error, did you find a solution?
